# Set a class variable as a reference given a reference in constructor

Tags: c++

Say I am given a class constructor:

#### .h file

```
class Memo {
    public:
    typedef vector<Memo> MemoList;
    Memo (int id, Memo::MemoList &list);
    MemoList pile;
};
```

#### .cc file

```
Memo::Memo (int id, Memo::MemoList &list) {
    pile = list;
}
```

Would `pile` be the "same thing" or "equal to" `list`, or do I need to have a new variable which acts as a reference to `list`? I would like to be able to modify `pile` and have it affect the original `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your problem:

> do I need to have a new variable which acts as a reference to list? I
>   would like to be able to modify pile and have it affect the original
>   list.

:

You need to store the list as reference:

```
MemoList& pile;
//      ^
```

And reference must be initialized on initialization list of your constructor:

```
Memo::Memo (int id, Memo::MemoList &list) : pile(list) {
}
```

When your `Memo` would has to be copyable (now it is not) use pointer instead of reference.

And remember (maybe it should be told at first) that programming in this way is not very safe - you must be sure that your list lifetime is longer than your Memo objects!!!

Comment: I have just tried that, but I am given the error: `uninitialized reference member`

Comment: See second part of my response.

Comment: Ah, thank you - it compiles now. Just one additional question, is there a name/terminology for the `: pile(list)` part?

Comment: @Kirin of course: read this: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?464084-C-General-What-is-the-initialization-list-and-why-should-I-use-it, it is called initialization-list

Answer (score 0):

Make it a reference:

```
class Memo
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<Memo> MemoList;
    Memo(int id, MemoList & list) : pile(list) { }

private:
    MemoList & pile;
};
```

This will make your class unassignable, since you cannot reseat references. If that's a problem, use a `std::reference_wrapper<MemoList>` instead of the `MemoList &` (same semantics).